# Configure gitlab-runner, docker/compose and docker:dind to use an artifactory docker image hub mirror

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

There are various questions on how to use docker or docker-compose from the gitlab-ci.

So I am using the following Docker-Images for my quest:

- gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest  *(as the gitlab-runner instance)*
- docker/compose:1.29.2 *(as gitlab-ci.yml executor image)*
- docker:dind *(as service)*

```
image: docker/compose:1.29.2

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_HOSTNAME: myhost
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

services:
  - name: docker:dind

stages:
  - composeTest

composeTest:
  stage: composeTest
  tags:
    - compose
  script:
    - ping -c 3 docker
    - docker-compose --version
    - docker-compose up -d
    - docker-compose down
```

*Currently I disabled tls, I will work on this later. That is not content of this question!*

In this *script*, the first two commands are successfully processed, but `docker-compose up -d` fails when it tries to pull the required images.

On my server I also have a `.docker/config.json` file with content like

```
{
        "auths": {
                "local.artifactory.corp.net": {
                        "auth": "VERY SECURE KEY!"
                }
        },
        "proxy": {
                "remoteurl": "local.artifactory.corp.net"
        }
}
```

I figured, I need this config.json available in the docker-container, that pulls the required images.

- **But which of the three afforementioned containers is it?**
- **(How) can I get it there?** (Without maintaining a custom version of it?)

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is run `docker login` with your registry address/username/password.

something like this

```yaml
composeTest:
  before_script:
    - docker login local.artifactory.corp.net -u derm -p $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD
```

If you use SSO to sign into Artifactory, you may have to generate a token to use as your password.

There are a few techniques to authenticate to a private registry from GitLab CI. You can also take advantage of `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` environment variable mechanics, credential helpers, etc. This is explained in depth in the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#access-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was wrong and didn't need the *config.json* I found.

Instead I needed a */etc/docker/daemon.json* in the docker:dind-image with a line like

```
"registry-mirrors": ["https://local.artifactory.corp.net"]
```

I did not find a solution yet, on how to get it there, without creating a new image.